# When ID = certain value sum two values according to ID

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

The File# can appear multiple times. When file # =52,56,67 sum Reg Hours and O/T Hours. Also clear O/T Hours for 52,56,67.

Data:

[image]

I have tried to calculate by cell location then I realized the location is not fixed each time when I export a new report.

```
Sub Calculation()
  If range ("C2:C14")=52,56,67 THEN
    Range("G48").Formula = "=Sum(h48:i48)"
    Range("I48").Clear
    Range("G68").Formula = "=Sum(h68:i68)"
    Range("i68").Clear
    Range("G8").Formula = "=Sum(h8:i8)"
    Range("I8").Clear
  End If
End sub
```

My actual result clears the O/T hour before calculating. And it doesn't relate to the File #

Comment: Use `Pivot` table to get your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. `If` statement does not work quite like that...

`If range ("C2:C14")=52,56,67 THEN`

should be `If Range("C2:C14") = 52 or Range("C2:C14") = 56 or Range("C2:C14") = 67 Then...`

But for good practice, you should always qualify your ranges.. see below one way of doing what you are trying to achieve, and additional comments:

```vb
Sub Calculation()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet 'declare and allocate your worksheet, even better use .Sheets("sheet name")
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row 'get the last row in column C
    Dim R As Long

    For R = 2 To lRow 'iterate through all rows
        With ws
            Select Case .Cells(R, "C").Value
                Case 52, 56, 67
                    .Cells(R, "G") = .Cells(R, "H") + .Cells(R, "I") 'sum the values and allocate
                    .Cells(R, "I").Clear 'clear the value
            End Select
        End With
    Next R

End Sub
```